# Show that $\mathcal{F} = \{E, E_1, E_2, E_3 \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> In the extended reals, $\mathbb{R}$, let $E$ be a borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let
>   $$  E_1 = E \cup\{\infty\} ,  E_2 = E \cup\{-\infty\} ,  E_3 = E \cup\{-\infty, \infty\} . $$
>   Then $E, E_1, E_2, E_3 $ is a $\sigma$-algebra, with $E$ variying in the borelians.

What I understand of this problem is that I have to show that $\mathcal{F} = \{E, E_1, E_2, E_3 \}$ is a  $\sigma$-algebra.

$E \in \mathcal{F} .$ $E$ is any borel set, so it can be $X = \mathbb{R} $ or $\emptyset.$

Take $B \in \mathcal{F}.$ If $B=E,$ as $B$ is in a $ \sigma$-algebra, its complement is also there. So $B^c \in \mathcal{F}.$ (So far, I hope I am getting a correct idea of the proof). But what happens if $B=E_1, $ or  $B=E_2, $ or $B=E_3$? I don't see what is the complement of the set whose only element is infinity. $ E_1^c  = E^c \cap\{\infty\}^c.$ So I have no idea if this set is in $\mathcal{F}.$ A similar thing happens with $E_2, E_3.$

I would also have to verify that countable unions of elements in $\mathcal{F}$ are in $\mathcal{F}.$ For this I observed various cases:
$E \cup...\cup E = E,$ and $E\cup E_1 = E_1,$ $E\cup E_2 = E_2,$ $E\cup E_3 = E_3,$ $E_1\cup E_2 = E_3,$ $E_1\cup E_3 = E_3,$ $E_2\cup E_3 = E_3,$ $E_3\cup E_3 = E_3.$ So for more unions of the sets, I will most likely get $E_3,$ as the result, And $E_3 \in \mathcal{F}.$

For the countable intersection, I am not going to write down all the cases, but the most common intersection of sets will be $E.$ And in other cases, the intersection gives again something in $\mathcal{F}.$

I also beleive I am writing down to much, so I would appreciate an idea of how to simplify the writing, If the Idea of the proof is correct.

Comment: $E_1^{c}=E^{c} \cup \{-\infty\}$  etc. You don't have to consider intersections. Unions and complements automatically take care of intersections.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So $ \{\infty\}^c = \{-\infty\}. $ It makes sense. I still don't see why  $E_1^{c}=E^{c} \cup \{-\infty\}$ and why not use the DeMorgan laws to get $E_1^{c}= E^c \cap\{\infty\}^c.$ It is a union of sets.